# fetching device location in background on receive of an sms in android 8+

Tags: android, location, android-8.0-oreo

As per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits) if the app is in the background it can not request location updates frequently:

the definition of foreground is :

> The system distinguishes between foreground and background apps. An
>   app is considered to be in the foreground if any of the following is
>   true:
>
> - It has a visible activity, whether the activity is started or paused.
> - It has a foreground service.
> - Another foreground app is connected to
>     the app, either by binding to one of its services or by making use of
>     one of its content providers. For example, if a foreground app binds
>     to any of the following components within another app, that other app
>     is considered to be in the foreground:
>
>   - Input method editor (IME)
>   - Wallpaper service
>   - Notification listener
>   - Voice or text service
>
> If none
>   of those conditions is true, the app is considered to be in the
>   background.

I need to fetch users current location when user receives an sms, does `Voice and text service` criteria should be applicable for SMS broadcast receiver?

In my experiments, I found that it's not the case. am I missing something here?

Comment: How about if location settings turn off ? You can get location in background by starting foreground location getting service

Comment: @MD location in on. and yes it works if I start a foreground service to check location. however, starting foreground service is not desired for my use case.

Comment: Well in that case. You need to contact Google directly. You know google is putting more and more limitations in newer version of android due to lack of battery and other security reasons. I like this way of battery improvements

Comment: I would assume that you need a foreground service. I am not certain what exactly "voice or text service" means in the documentation. Also note that there are further restrictions on background location access in Android Q.

Comment: @CommonsWare [this other document](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) mentions that SMS broadcast brings the app in foreground whitelist for several minutes, shouldn't it be applicable for the location as well?  and thank you for the tip on Q, we are working on that as well.

Comment: "shouldn't it be applicable for the location as well?" -- `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @CommonsWare does `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` mean you don't know. sorry not aware of that lingo/meme

Comment: Sorry, the shruggie (`¯\_(ツ)_/¯`) means I don't know.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for the clarification.